# How to redirect ALL traffic from example.com to example.org with Rochen hosting so that HTTPS works

Tags: domains, redirects, duplicate-content

I'm using Namecheap (www.namecheap.com) domain with Rochen (www.rochen.com) host. I'd like ALL traffic to go from `example.com` to `example.org`.

Things I've tried:

1. cPanel alias. I could not get this to forward https
2. cPanel addon domain. I did not like this approach because it seems hacky and I had to create a dummy subdomain to get it to work.

Any suggestions here? I assume this is a common problem but googling it has been futile.

EDIT: Another suggestion has been to get the .com its own hosting plan and then set up SSL and redirects there. Still not sure what the best solution is here though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily from the Namecheap admin panel. Just go to your domain's list, click on your domain, and you can redirect that domain with all of if subpages to the website you want. All of my Namecheap domains are redirected this way.

`yourlink1.com` will be redirected to `yourlink1.org` and so on...

Comment: I can't seem to redirect https though...

Comment: @Justin you can't just simply type https in? If this is the case you should do it at the backend somehow. I am using Flask for this kind of stuff so I am not sure how to do that with cpanel. But with a simple Flask app it's quite easy if you know the URL's you would like to redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I used an alias through cpanel, set forwarding to the .org domain, and then updated the ssl cert to include both .com and .org domains. The main issue was updating the ssl cert.